# Setting default file encoding

Tags: node.js, file

I have  to pass the file encoding repetitively. Is there any option to set default file encoding?

```
var f=fs.readFileSync('foo.txt','utf8'); >> var f=fs.readFileSync('foo.txt');
```

> If the encoding option is specified then this function returns a
>   string. Otherwise it returns a buffer.

Comment: Default is buffer. So you would have to pass encoding. Try wrapping it in another function.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious way to do it would be to make a wrapper function.

```
function myReadFile(filename) {
  return fs.readFileSync(filename,'utf8');
}
var f = myReadFile('foo.txt');
```